# convert Enumeration<String> to Enumeration<object>

Tags: java

UPDATE:

```
private final java.util.Properties tilesPropertyMap = new Properties();   

private class DelegatingServletConfig implements ServletConfig {   

        public String getServletName() {   
            return "TilesConfigurer";   
        }   

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {   
        return servletContext;   
    }   

    public String getInitParameter(String paramName) {   
        return tilesPropertyMap.getProperty(paramName);   
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
       return tilesPropertyMap.keys(); // returns Enumeration<Object>
    }

}
```

**UPDATE: i am implementing ServletConfig so i have to getInitParameterNames()**

how would i convert Enumeration <String> to Enumeration <object>?

Comment: Please see update i'm using Properties that extends Hashtable<Object,Object>

Comment: I recommend to get rid of the `Properties` and use a `HashMap` instead. Or do you retrieve the `Properties` object from an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getInitParameterNames() {
        Enumeration tile = tilesPropertyMap.keys(); // returns Enumeration<Object>
        return tile;            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you initilized `tilesPropertyMap` this way (more or less):

```
tilesPropertyMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

The easiest solution would be to properly initialize the HashMap during creation, like this:

```
tilesPropertyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Now you do not have to cast anything, the method you've shown above would perfectly work. Or did I missunderstand your question?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done significant Java work but that can't possibly be correct syntax right?  Isn't the generic type parameters supposed to come after the type and not the parens?  Or is that something new that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Obviously you are right. I update the snippets. Thanks!

Comment: @home: Ok good, it was just surreal seeing that in two answers.  I thought thought for a second there that Java went in a weird direction.  :)

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Hope they are not going to introduce this language feature :-)

Comment: @Ravi Parekh: No prob, please make sure you accept one of the answers (if the problem is solved).

Answer (score 0):

i would not cast all map keys to String.

if you are really sure, that only strings are inside these keys, please change the map key type from object to string.

```
new HashMap()<String, Object>;
```

Casting the hole map keys, could throw a classcastexception and you would have to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean how do you convert `Enumeration<Object>` to `Enumeration<String>`...

You can't.

Instead, make `tilesPropertyMap` a `Map<String, ?>` instead of `Map<Object, ?>`

Comment: what about it? you mean how your answer doesn't compile?

Comment: in above case we don't need to convert. Object Automatically convert to String. In my posted  que. won't compile but if i put `Enumeration tile = tilesPropertyMap.keys();`

Comment: Maybe you should put your code into a complete java class and try to compile it and see what happens. Or, you could just trust me that you can't cast Enumeration<Object> to Enumeration<String>

Comment: may be you are right but for your information i'm using JRE/JDK 1.6.26 & even you can cast in collection `LinkedList<Object> to List<String> as well i have made some example and it also running.